# Best way to build json object from two querys and a joining table

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, web-services, express

I'm currently working on a small webservice in node for managing the commands in a restaurant. I'm using Express.js

in my database i got theese tables :

```
DISH(id,name)
COMMAND(id,table,status)
COMMAND_DISH(idCommand,idDish,quantity)
```

I would like to know if there is a way to build a JSON object like this for each command :

```
[
  {
    "idCommand": 1,
    "table": 21,
    "dishes": {
      "dish1": {
        "dishName1": "salad",
        "quantity": 2
      },
      "dish2": {
        "dishName1": "steak",
        "quantity": 2
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Knowing that my queries return rows like this

Command :

```
id table status
1    3    sent
2    4    sent
3    5    sent
```

Command_dish :

```
idCommand idDish quantity
    1       2       2
    1       3       2
    2       2       4
    2       1       1
    2       3       5
```

Dish :

```
id name
1  salad
2  steak
3  pasta
4  pizza
```

What i can't figure out here is how can i construct the json object when i got several commandId from command_dish

**EDIT : So far this is how i try to build the data but i'm not sure about the query inside the query, is it doable ?**

```
app.get("/commandes", function(req, res, next) {
var restaurant = req.query.restaurant;
connection.connect();
var tableauCommande= new Object();
connection.query('SELECT * FROM COMMANDE WHERE restaurant=?',restaurant,function(err, rows, fields) {
    if (err) throw err;
    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        var tableauResult = new Object();
        tableauResult["idCommande"]=rows[i].id;
        tableauResult["table"]=rows[i].taable;      
        var tableauPlats = new Object();
        connection.query('SELECT P.label, C.quantite FROM PLAT AS P, COMMANDE_PLAT AS C WHERE C.plat=P.id AND C.commande=?',rows[i].id,function(err, rows, fields) {
            if (err) throw err;             
            for (var j = 0; j < rows.length; j++) {
                tableauPlats[rows[j].label]=rows[j].quantite;
            }
            tableauResult["plats"]=JSON.stringify(tableauPlats);
            JSON.stringify(tableauResult);
        });
        tableauCommande[rows[i].id]=JSON.stringify(tableauResult);
    }
});
});
```

**EDIT2 : I changed the code to this :**

```
app.get("/commandes", function(req, res, next) {
var restaurant = req.query.restaurant;
var tableauResult= new Object();
connection.connect();   
connection.query('SELECT * FROM COMMANDE WHERE restaurant=?',restaurant,function(err, rows, fields) {
    if (err) throw err;
    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        var tableauCommande = new Object();             
        tableauCommande["table"]=rows[i].taable;        
        tableauResult[rows[i].id]=tableauCommande;
    }
}); 
connection.end();
console.log(tableauResult);
for (var key in tableauResult) {
    var tableauPlats = new Object();
    connection.connect();               
    connection.query('SELECT P.label, C.quantite FROM PLAT AS P, COMMANDE_PLAT AS C WHERE C.plat=P.id AND C.commande=?',key,function(err, rows, fields) {
        if (err) throw err;             
        for (var j = 0; j < rows.length; j++) {
            tableauPlats[rows[j].label]=rows[j].quantite;
        }
        tableauResult[key]["plats"]=tableauPlats;
    });
    connection.end();
}
    console.log(tableauResult);
});
```

it seems more stable but i'm getting a "Cannot enqueue Query after invoking quit" error. I don't understand since i manage the connections properly

Comment: You can construct JSON from the data, yes.  Please post some code showing how you currently get the data, and how it's held in order to help parse it into the structure you require.

Comment: i will do it asap

Comment: see the edit @Archer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is interested i managed to build the json object like this

```
app.get("/commandes", function(req, res, next) {
var restaurant = req.query.restaurant;
var tableauResult= new Object();
connection.connect();   
connection.query('SELECT CP.commande, C.taable, C.status, P.label, CP.quantite FROM PLAT AS P, COMMANDE AS C, COMMANDE_PLAT AS CP WHERE CP.plat=P.id AND C.id=CP.commande AND C.restaurant=?',restaurant,function(err, rows, fields) {
    if (err) throw err;
    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        if(rows[i].commande in tableauResult){
            tableauResult[rows[i].commande]["plats"][rows[i].label]=rows[i].quantite;
        }else{
            var tableauCommande = new Object();
            tableauCommande["table"]=rows[i].taable;
            tableauCommande["status"]=rows[i].status;               
            var tableauPlats = new Object();
            tableauPlats[rows[i].label]=rows[i].quantite;               
            tableauCommande["plats"]=tableauPlats;
            tableauResult[rows[i].commande]=tableauCommande;
        }
    }
    res.json(tableauResult);
});
connection.end();
});
```

what was tricky is that it seems that mysql node package don't like two queries even if you open and close the connection properly so i loaded everything in one single query and i had to sort the results myself.